# Is this for-in loop standards compliant?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to limit the number of local variables exposed to an `eval` housed in a isolated closure to keep the scope as unpolluted as possible. But I also need to traverse a passed array, so I am doing something very similar to this:

```
var oObj = [{
    key: "",
    arr: {
      "one": 1,
      "two": 2,
      "three": 3
    }
}];

for (oObj[0].key in oObj[0].arr) {
    console.log(oObj[0].arr[oObj[0].key]);
}
```

In my actual code, `oObj` is passed into the closure'd function as the first argument (e.g. `arguments[0]`) so that the only local variable exposed to the function is `arguments` (which is exposed anyway).

This code works as expected, but [jshint.com](http://www.jshint.com) lists no fewer than 12 warnings for this code block.

So... am I pushing the envelop too far here or am I standards compliant? Can a `for-in` loop use an `object.property` for the `key`? JSHint doesn't seem to think so while everything I've tried seems happy with it.

Comment: Note that there's a difference between what the specification allows (just about anything) and what is considered "best practice" (what linters such as JSLint and JSHint check). Just because it doesn't pass JSHint doesn't mean it's not valid JavaScript code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the ECMAScript standards](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4), the syntax for a for-in loop is

> *IterationStatement* **: for (** *LeftHandSideExpression* **in** *Expression* **)** *Statement*

And [a *LeftHandSideExpression* can be a *CallExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2), which furthermore can be a

> *CallExpression* **.** *IdentifierName*

So, yes, according to the standards, it is a valid for-in loop.

But is it confusing? Yes. Why not just do something like this:

```
for (key in oObj[0].arr) {
    oObj[0].key = key;
    console.log(oObj[0].arr[key]);
}
```

Comment: Because `key` then pollutes the local scope and can be erroneously changed in an `eval`. Now... so could `arguments` (so long as it's outside of a function) but that is less likely. It is definitely confusing! And I've simplified the code for the example above! I also use `while` and `shift` to spinn thru the JS to `eval` ;) Oh, and THANKS! I am standards compliant!

Comment: There's also `oObj[0].arr.forEach(...)` which might help with the scoping concerns.

Comment: Ohh... `.forEach`... I'd have to polyfill that for older browsers (sub IE8 from memory) but that might be a sneakier way to accomplish this without freaking out JSHint!?